# Is there a way I can shorten these if statements?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to check for equivalency in these values and I'm not sure if there is a way I can shorten up how many lines of code I'm producing here. My goal here is to return a distinct error that I can return in an Ajax call so my front end can produce a message to the user.

The code below is what I've tried so far, but I'm simply unsure how to proceed with reducing this code.

```
def check_ip_conflicts(primary_dns, secondary_dns, ip_start, ip_end, subnet_mask, gateway, left1bits):

    primary_dns = list(map(int, primary_dns.split(".")))
    secondary_dns = list(map(int, secondary_dns.split(".")))
    ip_start = list(map(int, ip_start.split(".")))
    ip_end = list(map(int, ip_end.split(".")))
    subnet = list(map(int, subnet_mask.split(".")))
    gateway = list(map(int, gateway.split(".")))

    network = []
    total_ips = num_ips_in_range(left1bits)

    ###bit wise & may have to change from ip_start to Primary DNS. Ask Dan possibly 
    for i in range(4):
        network.append(ip_start[i] & subnet[i])

    if primary_dns == secondary_dns:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS SECONDARY DNS ERROR"

    if primary_dns == subnet:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS SUBNET ERROR"

    if primary_dns == gateway:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS GATEWAY ERROR"

    if primary_dns == ip_start:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"

    if primary_dns == ip_end:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"

    if secondary_dns == subnet:
        return "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS SUBNET ERROR"

    if secondary_dns == gateway:
        return "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS GATEWAY ERROR"

    if secondary_dns == ip_start:
        return "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"

    if secondary_dns == ip_end:
        return "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"
    
    if subnet == gateway:
        return "SUBNET EQUALS GATEWAY ERROR"

    if subnet == ip_start:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"

    if subnet == ip_end:
        return "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"

    if gateway == ip_start:
        return "GATEWAY EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"
    
    if gateway == ip_end:
        return "GATEWAY EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"
```

Comment: Use `elif` for mutually exclusive conditions.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't matter at all here since there's a `return` in each condition.

Comment: @AKX I didn't notice that. Then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the values in a dictionary. Then you can loop over the dictionary looking for any conflicts.

```
def check_ip_conflicts(primary_dns, secondary_dns, ip_start, ip_end, subnet_mask, gateway, left1bits):

    primary_dns = list(map(int, primary_dns.split(".")))
    secondary_dns = list(map(int, secondary_dns.split(".")))
    ip_start = list(map(int, ip_start.split(".")))
    ip_end = list(map(int, ip_end.split(".")))
    subnet = list(map(int, subnet_mask.split(".")))
    gateway = list(map(int, gateway.split(".")))

    network = []
    total_ips = num_ips_in_range(left1bits)

    ###bit wise & may have to change from ip_start to Primary DNS. Ask Dan possibly 
    for i in range(4):
        network.append(ip_start[i] & subnet[i])

    checks = {"PRIMARY DNS": primary_dns, "SECONDARY DNS": secondary_dns, "SUBNET": subnet, "GATEWAY": gateway, "STARTING IP": ip_start, "ENDING IP": ip_end}

    for type1, value1 in checks.items():
        for type2, value2 in checks.items():
            if type1 != type2 and value1 == value2:
                return f"{type1} EQUALS {type2} ERROR"
    
    return "NO ERROR"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make things a little shorter *and* more user friendly might be

```
def check_ip_conflicts(primary_dns, secondary_dns, ip_start, ip_end, subnet_mask, gateway, left1bits):

    primary_dns = [int(x) for x in primary_dns.split(".")]
    secondary_dns = [int(x) for x in secondary_dns.split(".")]
    ip_start = [int(x) for x in ip_start.split(".")]
    ip_end = [int(x) for x in ip_end.split(".")]
    subnet = [int(x) for x in subnet_mask.split(".")]
    gateway = [int(x) for x in gateway.split(".")]

    network = []
    total_ips = num_ips_in_range(left1bits)

    ###bit wise & may have to change from ip_start to Primary DNS. Ask Dan possibly
    for i in range(4):
        network.append(ip_start[i] & subnet[i])

    return [
        error
        for (flag, error) in [
            (primary_dns == secondary_dns, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS SECONDARY DNS ERROR"),
            (primary_dns == subnet, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS SUBNET ERROR"),
            (primary_dns == gateway, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS GATEWAY ERROR"),
            (primary_dns == ip_start, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"),
            (primary_dns == ip_end, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"),
            (secondary_dns == subnet, "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS SUBNET ERROR"),
            (secondary_dns == gateway, "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS GATEWAY ERROR"),
            (secondary_dns == ip_start, "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"),
            (secondary_dns == ip_end, "SECONDARY DNS EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"),
            (subnet == gateway, "SUBNET EQUALS GATEWAY ERROR"),
            (subnet == ip_start, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"),
            (subnet == ip_end, "PRIMARY DNS EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"),
            (gateway == ip_start, "GATEWAY EQUALS STARTING IP ERROR"),
            (gateway == ip_end, "GATEWAY EQUALS ENDING IP ERROR"),
        ]
        if flag
    ]
```

This changes the function to return a list of errors, not only the first one it comes across.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that if there are no errors present I want to return something to signify that everything is good to go. So rather than simply returning a list of errors, it would be either return a list of errors OR return True or something.

Comment: This will return an empty list in that case.